# plone.app.caching and disabling RAM cache

Tags: caching, plone

I'd like to use plone.app.caching for front-end proxy caching only (Varnish). By default, plone.app.caching comes with RAM cache settings. To make caching simpler, easier to diagnose, I'd like to cache stuff only in the front end cache.

- Can plone.app.caching RAM cache disabled by setting cached object count to zero?
- Does this have any known bad effects on the site?
- Are there any other ways to disable RAM cache?
- Is RAM cache enabled on vanille Plone installations (no plone.app.caching installed)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn the RAM cache on/off on a per-ruleset basis. Go to the Caching control panel, to the Detailed Settings tab, and go to "View/edit/clear per-ruleset paramaters" for each operation to find the setting.